# Unity 2D Platformer: Jump animation breaks when Player Object turned into a Prefab. Any solutions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, prefab

I'm currently working on a 2D Platformer in Unity. I followed along Brackeys Tutorials (will post links below) and everything works like intended, except when I turn my Player Object into a prefab. Then suddenly my Jump Animation breaks for some reason. Does anyone know a solution for this problem, because im not sure whether it's a programming problem or a unity related issue.

Tutorials I used:

#1 https://youtu.be/dwcT-Dch0bA
#2 https://youtu.be/hkaysu1Z-N8

Bugged Animation video: https://youtu.be/1EnmG8mfVvs

The left player character in the video is the prefab with the bugged animation.

Would be really awesome if someone can help me :)

Kind Regards,

Jean-Pierre

I've tried changing some of my code, also tried re-animating the Object as a Prefab, and searched online for similar problems, but couldn't find anything.

This is my PlayerMovement.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController2D controller;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;
    bool jump = false;
    bool crouch = false;
    public Animator animator;


    public float coyoteTime = 0.2f;
    public float coyoteTimeCounter = 0;

    public float jumpBufferTime = 0.2f;
    public float jumpBufferCounter;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

        if (controller.m_Grounded)
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;
        }
        else
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
            jumpBufferCounter = jumpBufferTime;
        }
        else
        {
            jumpBufferCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump"))
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter = 0f;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnLanding()
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
    }

    public void OnCrouching(bool isCrouching)
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", isCrouching);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump, jumpBufferCounter);
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

and this is my CharacterController2D.cs

```
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
    [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
    [Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  // How much to smooth out the movement
    [SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                         // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                          // A mask determining what is ground to the character
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
    [SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          // A position marking where to check for ceilings
    [SerializeField] private Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                // A collider that will be disabled when crouching

    const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
    public bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
    const float k_CeilingRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
    private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
    private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
    private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;
    private PlayerMovement player;


    [Header("Events")]
    [Space]

    public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

    public BoolEvent OnCrouchEvent;
    private bool m_wasCrouching = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        player = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();

        if (OnLandEvent == null)
            OnLandEvent = new UnityEvent();

        if (OnCrouchEvent == null)
            OnCrouchEvent = new BoolEvent();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
        m_Grounded = false;

        // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
        // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
            {
                m_Grounded = true;
                if (!wasGrounded)
                    OnLandEvent.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Water"))
        {
            m_Grounded = true;
            m_JumpForce = m_JumpForce = 800;
            m_Rigidbody2D.gravityScale = 0.8f;
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Water"))
        {
            m_Rigidbody2D.gravityScale = 3f;
            m_JumpForce = 800;
        }
    }

    public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump, float jumpBufferTimer)
    {
        // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
        if (!crouch)
        {
            // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
            if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
            {
                crouch = true;
            }
        }

        //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
        if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
        {

            // If crouching
            if (crouch)
            {
                if (!m_wasCrouching)
                {
                    m_wasCrouching = true;
                    OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(true);
                }

                // Reduce the speed by the crouchSpeed multiplier
                move *= m_CrouchSpeed;

                // Disable one of the colliders when crouching
                if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                    m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = false;
            } else
            {
                // Enable the collider when not crouching
                if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                    m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = true;

                if (m_wasCrouching)
                {
                    m_wasCrouching = false;
                    OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(false);
                }
            }

            // Move the character by finding the target velocity
            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

            // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
            if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
            // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
            else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
        }
        // If the player should jump...
        if (player.coyoteTimeCounter > 0f && jumpBufferTimer > 0f)
        {
            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
            player.jumpBufferCounter = 0f;
        }
    }


    private void Flip()
    {
        // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
        m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Edit: I think it has something to do with the UnityEvent in CharacterController2D.cs

new Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6yxyafyUVg

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Looks like your prefab is missing animator/animation or some how the transition is not firing. Can you show inspector for both players and also the console window while playing game.

Comment: Hey @waqasali. Yes, I can do that later, but I'm pretty sure now, it has something to do with my UnityEvent "OnLandEvent". Because if I remove my "OnLanding" function from the Inspectior in the "OnLandEvent", then my jump animation is kinda working. 

If I dont disable it you can see in the Animator window, that my parameter "IsJumping" is getting triggered to "true" for like 0.2 seconds or so and then back to "false".

I'll upload a more detailed video later, but thanks for your quick reply :)

Comment: @waqasali I've updated the thread and posted a new video. :)

Comment: @Yeriwen In the PlayerMovement  Script add this code and check
void Start()
{
animator=this.gameObject.GetComponenet<Animator>();
}